# How do you calculate the expected value of an event that after it succeeds, it is guaranteed to fail for the next n trials?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I came across an expected value problem that I had no clue how to begin tackling. It is as follows:

An event $X$ has a $20$% chance of occurring every second. However, once it has occurred, it cannot occur again for the next 5 seconds. What is the expected number of occurrences of $X$ over:

a. $50$ seconds?

b. $n$ seconds?

The only thing I could think of is manually processing each circumstance but that sounds impractical.

Note: A user brought up a good point and I would assume each second is  one trial, so it is a discrete process.

Comment: Are you analysing this process as discrete in seconds or continuous in time?

Comment: Assuming you are looking at a discrete process, I'd work recursively.  $E_{N}=.2\times (1+E_{N-6})+.8\times E_{N-1}$.  (Note:  check the $N-6$.  I didn't think that hard about the shift in that case).

Comment: @Tyler L:  Does the phrase "over $50$ seconds" mean the *first* $50$ seconds, i.e., times $1,2,3,...50$?

Comment: @lulu: My answer (which I worked out independently) uses the same approach as you suggested in your comment. But the numerical results based on my approach don't match the results based on the formula given by r.e.s. Can you weigh in on the issue?

Comment: @quasi  I don't understand the approach posed by that user.  The recursion really ought to work.  Ibndicator variables are not applicable since we would need to keep track of the history of trials.

Comment: @lulu: Thank you very much for your analysis and insights with regard to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $e(n)$ is the expected number of occurrences of $X$ in $n$ seconds, then $e$ satisfies the recursion
$$
e(n)=\frac{4}{5}e(n-1)+\frac{1}{5}\bigl(1+e(n-6)\bigr)
$$
for all $n\ge 1$, together with the initial conditions $e(n)=0$ for all $n\le 0$.

Applying the recursion for $n=50$, we get
$$
e(50)
=
\frac
{
457411872356289460786855993941735249\,
}{
88817841970012523233890533447265625
}
\approx
5.149999845
$$

Comment: I agree with this result (+1)  For a (crude) heuristic count the  "possible" days (those that aren't locked out by a prior success).  We see that they are given by $\frac 1p\times E_n$ on the one hand and by $n-5E_n$ on the other.    We conclude that $\frac n{E_n}\sim 5+\frac 1p$.  That's $10$ in this case.  Running the recursion out to $n=1000$ I get $9.985022466$

Comment: A quick way to see that the formula oproposed by @r.e.s. is wrong is to let $p=1$.  In that case, we clearly get a win every $6^{th}$ trial, so $E_n\sim \frac n6$.  But their formula yields $E_n=0$.